# Geometric interpretation of this condition

Tags: dynamical-systems, vector-fields, geometric-interpretation

In a Differential Equations context we have the following theorem:

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ Let $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be some open set and $f:D\to\mathbb{R}^n$ a $\mathscr{C}^1$ vector field. Then, for every $x_0\in D$ there are real numbers $\alpha,\beta>0$ and a $\mathscr{C}^1$ map $\varphi$ from
$$I_\alpha\times B_\beta=\{(t,x)\mid \vert t\vert<\alpha\text{ and }\vert x-x_0\vert<\beta\}$$
to $D$ such that, for every $(t,x)\in I_\alpha\times B_\beta$ we have
$$D_t\varphi(t,x)=f(\varphi(t,x))\quad\text{ and }\quad\varphi(0,x)=x$$
$$D_tD_x\varphi(t,x)=Df(\varphi(t,x))(D_x\varphi(t,x))\quad\text{ and }\quad D_x\varphi(0,x)=Id_{B_\beta}$$

$\textbf{Interpretation:}$ For $n=2$ I think of this theorem as follows: you have a plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ and a vector field on the plane. For $x_0$ in the plane we can take a cylinder "centered" at $x_0$ with base $B_\beta$ and height $2\alpha$. The cylinder is like a tube full of vertical spaghetti (one for every $x\in B_\beta$) and each spaghetti gets mapped by $\varphi$ to an integral curve of the field $f$ that at time $t=0$ passes through $x$. This is the same as saying $\varphi_x(t)=\varphi(t,x)$ is a solution of the differential equation
$$\mathbf{u}'(t)=f(\mathbf{u}(t))\quad\quad \mathbf{u}(0)=x$$
So far so good. The second condition (which involves the $D_x$ and $Df$) must be saying something about how the solution $\varphi_x$ changes with $x$ but I don't know what exactly. I've tried interpreting it in many ways but don't find anything close to satisfactory.

Also, as I see it if $f(x_0)=0$ then the integral curves close to $x_0$ should be closed/periodic orbits and that doesn't seem to work nicely with my visualization

The closest thing I found is the rectification theorem but I can't connect both statements

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity
$$D_tD_x\varphi(t,x)=Df(\varphi(t,x))(D_x\varphi(t,x))$$
says that the linearization $D_x\varphi(t,x)$ of a solution along the initial conditions is a solution of the linearization
$$y'=Df(\varphi(t,x))y$$
of the original equation along that solution. The latter is
usually called a *linear variational equation*.

This means that the dependence of the solutions on the initial conditions can essentially be determined by studying the solutions of linear variational equations.

> Let's take your example $f(\bar x_0)=0$.
>
> In this case you get the equation $$y'=Ay\quad\text{with} \quad A=Df(\bar x_0).$$ This means that in order to understand how the solutions depend on the initial condition $x_0$ in a neighborhood of the original point $\bar x_0$ or, if you prefer, in a neighborhood of a critical point (but you need not have $f(x_0)=0$ for $x_0$ in the neighborhood), basically what matters are simply the eigenvalues of $A$ since the solutions of linear variational equation are obtained from $e^{At}$.

Something similar happens when the trajectory of $\bar x_0$ is periodic, although you need to study the much more complicated equation $y'=A(t)y$ with $A(t)$ periodic.

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly is linearization and why should it be a condition asked for?

Comment: Please ask a different question then (it is unrelated to your original question).

Comment: Okay thanks anyway!